# How to register a Django model for a specific database only

Tags: python, django, django-admin, multi-tenant

I am building a DJango multi-tenant web app that separates the tenants by giving them each their database. The app identifies the source and destination of the requests by checking the hostname. The `localhost` is the default tenant(me) using the `default` database and the subdomains from that are the tenants using their databases.

There is a model `Tenants` that I am using to create tenants and store their data. I want it to be only registered in the `default` database so that only I can SEE and edit it from the `localhost` admin but the tenant's admin can't.

I tried this and the only output was:

`------------------------------TenantAdmin------------------------------`

`admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Tenant
from .utils import hostname_from_the_request
# Register your models here.


class TenantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    print("------------------------------TenantAdmin------------------------------")
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # Get the hostname from the request
        current_hostname = hostname_from_the_request(request)
        print("------------------------------Current hostname B4------------------------------", current_hostname)

        # Check if the hostname is 'localhost'
        if current_hostname == 'localhost':
            return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("------------------------------Current hostname------------------------------", current_hostname)
            return None  # Returning None effectively hides the model in the admin

# Register the Tenant model with the custom admin class

admin.site.register(Tenant, TenantAdmin)
```

So I also tried interfering with the migrations in the routers:
`routers.py`

```
class TenantRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return get_current_db_name()

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return get_current_db_name()
    
    def allow_relation(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return True

    def allow_syncdb(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        print(f"----------------Checking migration for app: {app_label}, model: {model_name}, database: {db}------")
        if db == 'default' and model_name == 'Tenant':
            print(f"Allowing migration only for database: DEFAULT")
            return db == 'default'
        return None
```

That did not work either. I can still see the `Tenant` model in the admins of the tenants. Any ideas?